# How do you change the icon of a placemark entry in a KMLTreeView using the GE Winforms API

Tags: c#, google-earth-plugin

I would like to be able to change the icon of placemark entry in a KMLTreeView from a flag to some other custom bitmap.  It is not readily apparent to me that this can be done but if someone knows how can you please provide a few lines of code?

Here is a pic of the 'flag' I would like to change.

[image]

And here is the code that appears to set this icon.  I cannot find where the string "flag" is converted to an image.  This code is from the file KmlTreeViewNode.cs of the API dated 11/20/2012:

```
    internal void SetStyle()
    {
        switch (this.ApiType)
        {
            // other lines of code //

            case ApiType.KmlPlacemark:
                {
                    this.ImageKey = "flag";
                    this.SelectedImageKey = "flag";
                }
            // more lines of code //
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Please can you post questions about the KmlTreeView on the wiki project page for the control? http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/KmlTreeView - That way other users can find help easily. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  I was posting everything here because it said the Google API Support Group was moved to here.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was just lumping it all together.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Fraser, I've attempted to add a couple of comments/questions to the wiki link above but neither of them are shown.  Is the comment section turned off or have those comments been moderated out perhaps?

Comment: About the 'Changing the text color' - they just take a few mins to appear I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to replace the flag image file with your desired file and then recompile the library.

The image itself is a 16x16 pixel bitmap and is stored in an `ImageList` within the `KmlTreeView` control. Simply replace the flag image with the one you desire (remove the flag image then add a new image at index 2) then recompile the library.

[image: KmlTreeView Image list collection editor]

Alternatively you can simply add a new ImageList to the KmlTreeView. If you do this you should make sure that the images have the same names and indices.

```
kmlTreeView1.ImageList = this.myImageList;
```